# What happened to "audio" from AVP SE?

Tags: discussion

Just noticed the site was renamed from "audio-video production" to just "video production".
The url changed from [`avp`](http://avp.stackexchange.com) to [`video`](http://video.stackexchange.com) dot stackexchange dot com.

But an http://audio.stackexchange.com is missing. [The supposedly two sites were seemingly merged in 2011](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/audio-se-becoming-audio-video-production) originally.

Why was the site renamed now? Is there any point removing it from the title? What is the future of audio SE? Are audio questions still welcome here? What will happen to the existing audio legacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the meta questions a bit further down you will see extensive discussion

[Audio went off to merge with Sound Design](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343/674)... Not fully integrated yet, but hopefully getting there. All the audio questions were migrated over, although a handful of audio questions that are video specific remained.

Comment: thanks! I did a search for audio back then on meta, I just didn't cut it. Now the eluded stuff found me, thanks!